# What is the name of the approach where you store the history in the same table?

Tags: database, relational-database

I'm developing an application that uses a mysql database and we wanted to do an approach for history purposes, that we store the current state and the history in the same table for performance reasons (on updates the application doesn't have the id for an entity just a key pair, so it is easier just to insert a new row).

The table looks like this:

```
+------+-------+-----------+------------------------------+
| id   |user_id|    type   |content                       |
+------+-------+-----------+------------------------------+
| 1    |'1-2-3'|  position | *creation                    |
| 2    |'1-2-3'|  position | *something_changed           |
| 3    |'1-2-3'|   device  | *creation                    |
| 4    |'1-2-4'|  position | *creation                    |
| 5    |'1-2-4'|   device  | *creation                    |
| 6    |'1-2-4'|   device  | *something_changed           |
+------+-------+-----------+------------------------------+
```

Every entity is described with the user_id and type "key" pair, when something is changed in the entity a new row is inserted. The current state of an entity is selected by the highest id row from the group, which is grouped by the user_id and type. Performance wise the updates should be super fast and the selects can be slower, because those are not used often.

I would like to look up best practices and other people experiences with this method, but I don't know how to search for them. Can you help me? I'm interested in your experiences or opinions on this topic as well.

I know about Kafka and other streaming platforms, but that was sadly not an option for this.

Comment: Is your example table right? The last two rows have the same 'key' values (from what you say), but differ in `content` only. So what's declared as the SQL `KEY` for this table? This table doesn't include any column I'd recognise as the 'business key' (like Customer number, Employee id, vehicle rego, ...).

Comment: @AntC Thank you for noticing, I fixed it. The id is unique and sequenced.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database  might be relevant. What you show so far is one table, _not_ a database. And it seems to be 'audit' or tracing data, not business content. I'm surprised there isn't some sort of timestamp. The trouble with Temporal Databases is as soon as you have more than one table, how do you connect disparate events (changes of state) across multiple entities. For example: what was the position of this device at this time, and which user was using it? Is there a problem with this device? Or is it with this device at this position?

Comment: @AntC there are no more to show, this a place to store this data where this application is not the master of the user entity, so it just have a string I'd of it, which can used to identify across the other systems. The position and the device is not tied together, and irrelevant to each other(the position is not sent by the device it is just the currently used one, by the user). So there should be no problem.

Comment: @AntC this temporal database is the one I was looking for, thank you for your answer.